# How to properly find the matching character in another string

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

i would like to know the best way to compare a single character of a string to another whole string and find the matching character so to say. The probably most important snippets of my code are the user input request:
`string text = get_string("text:  ");`
and my predefined "comparison"-string= `char lowerabc[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`
Now, i would like to take the n-th value of the text and find the matching character in lowerabc.
My first try was to use a for-loop and set the end-criteria to when their values match, smth like this: `for(int j=0;text[i] == lowerabc[j] ; j++){}`
but as i've found out this compares the address of both and therefore makes no sense. Therefore i stumbled upon the strcmp() function and edited the code to match the zero-value as the end criteria: `for(int j=0;strcmp(text[i], lowerabc[j])==0 ; j++){}` but once i compile it, it throws me the error: `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]` Im sorry, but it really seems like that im too stubborn to make out the difference in nature of these two variables so that it would say smth like that to me. So therefore i would like to ask what would be the most efficient way to do this type of comparison. Ty all very much for your help

Comment: text[i] == lowerabc[j] does not compare addresses

Comment: Hint: What is text[i]? What is lowerabc[j]?

Comment: You lost me a bit in your post, but based on the title in the question, simply loop through the string and compare each `char` in it to the `char` you want to find. Or if you don't need to roll your own, you can use [`strchr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Comment: well to my understanding text [i] is the i-th character of the string text while lowerabc[j] is the j-th char of the string (or char array, which is the same meaning as a string?) lowerabc

Comment: tyvm yano, seems like thats way easier than what i tried to fabricate and it seems to be working too^^

Comment: your post makes it sound like you want to see which letters exist in your string? Eg, "Is 'a' in my string? Is 'b' in my string?, etc". Is that what you want? In that case, you can loop over your `lowerabc` string, and either call `strchr` or use an inner loop that searches thru all characters in your search string. Looks like you know this, but also be aware that case matters, `'a' != 'A'`. If you're using `strchr` that's especially pertinent. If you're rolling your own look at [`tolower`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strchr()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.htm) to find single character from a string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* mock */
typedef char* string;
string get_string(const char* x) {
    static char ret[] = "hoge123abc";
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    string text = get_string("text:  ");
    char lowerabc[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char* res = strchr(lowerabc, text[i]);
        if (res != NULL) {
            int idx = res - lowerabc;
            printf("%c is found at lowerabc[%d]\n", text[i], idx);
        } else {
            printf("%c is not found in lowerabc\n", text[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
h is found at lowerabc[7]
o is found at lowerabc[14]
g is found at lowerabc[6]
e is found at lowerabc[4]
1 is not found in lowerabc
2 is not found in lowerabc
3 is not found in lowerabc
a is found at lowerabc[0]
b is found at lowerabc[1]
c is found at lowerabc[2]
```

Comment: ty2, your example helps me understand the working behind this function very well, keep it up